# Library not recognized in Linux environment

Tags: ruby, linux, eclipse, unix, fxruby

I installed "eclipse" and want to run "fxruby" on fedora "linux", but it does not work it.
The error says :

> cannot load such file -- fox16 (LoadError)

I installed this file with command

```
gem install fxruby
```

but *fxruby* not exist in gem list.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Does this help you? http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/278329

Comment: Did you get errors when you ran `gem install fxruby`, and if so, what are they?

Comment: thanks for answer , when i run it ,say :>WARNING:  You don't have /home/B/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fxruby:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: current directory: /home/B/.gem/ruby/gems/fxruby-1.6.39/ext/fox16_c
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181104-9921-l96zxe.rb extconf.rb
checking for fox per pkg-config... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved** for fedora

---

i installed all of them :

> `ruby-devel.x86_64`
>
> `fox-devel.x86_64`
>
> `sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config`
>
> `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
>
> `yum group info 'Development Tools' yum -y install gcc ruby-devel`
>
> `rubygems compass`
>
> `gcc compt gcc-c++-x86_64-linux-gnu.x86_64`
>
> `gcc-c++`
>
> [
>              gcc-c++-8.2.1-4.fc28.x86_64    C++ support for GCC
>             libstdc++-devel-8.2.1-4.fc28.x86_64 Header files and libraries for C++ development
>
> ]
>
> `sudo dnf install libpng12-devel.x86_64`
>
> `sudo dnf install libb2-devel.x86_64`
>
> `sudo dnf install libX11-devel`
>
> `sudo dnf install libXcursor-devel.x86_64`
>
> `sudo dnf install   libXext-devel.x86_64 libXrandr-devel.x86_64`
>
> `gem install fxruby`

Answer (score 0):

The warning about the path you can safely ignore (at least for now).  What the error is telling you is that you do not have the FOX development headers and libraries installed, so it couldn't build the fxruby gem.  So you must install the fox development package - it may be named something like "fox16" or "fox16-devel", or something else depending on what version of Linux you're running.  (If all else fails, you can build it yourself).

After that, compiling fxruby (using `gem install fxruby`) should work.

If you *do* want to build FOX yourself, here are (approximately) the steps:

1) Go to the FOX website http://www.fox-toolkit.org/ , and download the latest 1.6 (stable) version (at the moment, fox-1.6.57.tar.gz).

2) I would create a directory ~/src, then `cd ~/src`, and unpack the downloaded package, e.g., `tar xvf ~/Downloads/fox-1.6.57.tar.gz` (adjust the path according to wherever you have actually downloaded the package).

2) You should now have a subdirectory `fox-1.6.57` (i.e., `~/src/fox-1.6.57/`).  Cd to it, and read top-level documentation in README and INSTALL.

3) Run the configure script, `./configure` *or* `./configure --prefix=$HOME`.
The difference between these invocations is that if you run a plain  `./configure`, the software will be installed under the default location /usr/local (this will require root access when installed), whereas the invocation  `./configure --prefix=$HOME` will result in the software being installed under $HOME.  The latter will not require root access to install and probably is better if you're just installing the software for your own use.

4) I you *are* installing under your own home directory, create appropriate subdirectories:  `cd ~; mkdir bin include lib`'.  (The installation *may* take care of this, but it doesn't hurt to pre-create the directories.)

5) Now run `make`.  That should compile and build the FOX libraries under the local directory (~/src/fox-1.6.57/)

6) Run `make install`.  That will install the libraries under either the default location of /usr/local or your home directory ~ (depending on your `configure` option)

7) A this point, you should have the FOX libraries and headers installed.  Now try `gem install fxruby`.  (If you're going for a local install, probably `gem install fxruby --user-install`.)

Comment: thank you for help me. after i fund all dependencies , i write them.